# Autocorrelation function in matlab without using built-in function

Tags: matlab, signals, correlation, autocorrelation

I am trying to write a code for the colculate autocorrelation function. Could you suggest what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

```
 i = 1:199;
    U =sin(0.3*i);
    sum_1 = 0;
    for tau = 1:length(U)
       for   t = tau:length(U)-1
           
             sum_1 = sum_1+sum(U(t).*U(t+1-tau));
             r(tau)=sum_1;
        end
    end
```

Comment: Look at your value `sum_1`, what does it contain after each iteration of the loop? You keep adding values to it all throughout the computation. Does that match the equation for the correlation function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. This is an implementation of the original algorithm with only a small optimization; calculating half the sequence and copying the remaining half.

```
n = length(x);
m = 2*n - 1;
rxx = zeros(1,m);
for i = 1:length(x)
    rxx(i) = dot(x(n-i+1:n), x(1:i).');
    rxx(m-i+1) = rxx(i)';
end
```

Example:

```
x = [2, 3, -1];

rxx =
    -2     3    14     3    -2

% MATLAB built-in
xcorr(x,x)
ans =
    -2     3    14     3    -2
```